Issue with Spring 6 security and Jakarta EE 10
I was migrating my application from Spring 5 to Spring 6 and Jakarta EE 10
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 

However, I am unable to deploy the application to Tomcat 10 and Payara 6 with the following error
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.util.List]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain' to required type 'jakarta.servlet.Filter': no matching editors or conversion strategy found. Please see server.log for more details.
How can I fix it?

Show your dependencies, for example your POM.
